# NetworkManager does not support 2FA TOTP for openconnect/AnyConnect VPN

Tags: network-manager, vpn, cisco, two-factor-authentication

I have been using the NetworkManager with my Unis' VPN for years, and it used to work. Now they introduced multi-factor authentification using TOTP and I can't connect anymore.

I tried to setup the VPN, using Cisco AnyConnect, entered the correct gateway and selected the token mode 'TOTP-manually entered'. When I try to connect, I first have to enter my usual user name and password, which works as before without the MFA. In the next step I get asked for the one time password, but there is no way to enter it... There just is no textbox for it. Is this just a bug in the network manager or a do I need to change some settings? How do I get this running?

I would like to keep using NetworkManager! I am using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.

Thanks to anyone who can help!

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: @waltinator the question describes exactly the problem. It is also correctly tagged. Can you please offer at least some indication of what is not OK in the question?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is a bug: Keep an eye on the relevant issue thread [NM doesn't ask for TOTP with openconnect](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/-/issues/1451) upstream, as well as the linked merge request [libnmc: support 2FA authentication from VPN plugins](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/-/merge_requests/1842).

In the meantime, since this is would be a bug in NetworkManager only (and not in the underlying openconnect), you should be able to use openconnect directly to establish a connection:

```
sudo openconnect --protocol=anyconnect --useragent=AnyConnect your-vpn-server.address.com
```

Comment: Yes, that looks like my bug. You are right, I can connect in the terminal, thanks for this advice!

Comment: sadly not working for me (using Debian 12). the terminal asks for username/pwd. Then terminates the session with `You have no dial-in permission` and reloops to asking user/pwd.

Comment: I had installed the Cisco Secure Client as recommended by my Uni before seeing this answer, which also works for me. Not really what I wanted, and I am very happy that I have an alternative now, but it was better than not having access to my stuff. Maybe something similar would work for you too, as a last resort? However, I think your problem might also be different than mine, it somehow sounds as if there is something wrong with your networks settings ((?) I have not much knowledge about that) for your user? Do you have some IT service that you can ask about that?